# \PrintChanges in dtx file does not produce output

Tags: documentation

I'm trying to compile several .dtx files containing a `\PrintChanges` command, but those never produce a *Change History* chapter. For example, I tried this on [Joseph Wright's self-extracting demopkg.dtx](https://www.texdev.net/uploads/2009/10/demopkg.dtx):

```
tex demopkg.dtx
pdflatex demopkg.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist demopkg.idx
pdflatex demopkg.dtx
```

Again: no Change history section, although there are two calls to `\changes`; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need a separate run of `makeindex` for the changes, which are written to a `.glo` file by `pdflatex`.

Compile sequence:

```
pdflatex demopkg.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist demopkg.idx
makeindex -s gglo.ist demopkg.glo -o demopkg.gls
pdflatex demopkg.dtx
```

Note that the `\PrintChanges` command expects a `.gls` file which you need to specify explicitly as output file in the second `makeindex` command.

Output of the two `makeindex` runs:

```
$ makeindex -s gind.ist demopkg.idx
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/makeindex/latex/gind.ist.............done (13 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file demopkg.idx....done (3 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (5 comparisons).
Generating output file demopkg.ind....done (14 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in demopkg.ind.
Transcript written in demopkg.ilg.

$ makeindex -s gglo.ist demopkg.glo -o demopkg.gls
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/makeindex/latex/gglo.ist..............done (14 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file demopkg.glo....done (2 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).
Generating output file demopkg.gls....done (10 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in demopkg.gls.
Transcript written in demopkg.ilg.
```

Document output:

[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't suspect a relation with indexes, thanks, this works great!